# No default constructor exists for class c++

Tags: c++, default-constructor, anonymous-objects

Hello,
I'm trying to instantiate an anonymous object with a std::string variable 'name'. But intellisenen gives me error saying

```
E0291   no default constructor exists for class "Player"    GoldGame    e:\C++ Projects\Hello World\GoldGame\GoldGame.cpp   17
```

I have provided a constructor which can just take a std::string variable since other parameters are provided with default value.

Can you guys shed some light on this?

What confuses me even more is that when I change

```
Player(name);
```

to

```
Player a(name);
```

or to

```
Player("test");
```

then intellisense becomes totally fine with those.

---

GoldGame.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Creature.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;

    Player(name);


    return 0;
}
```

Creature.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class Creature
{
public:
    Creature(const std::string &name, const char symbol, const int health, const int damage, const int gold);
    ~Creature();

    //getters
    const std::string& getName() { return m_name; }
    const char getSymbol() { return m_symbol; }
    const int getHealth() { return m_health; }
    const int getDamage() { return m_damage; }
    const int getGold() { return m_gold; }

    //health, gold and dead 
    void reduceHealth(const int healthMinus);
    void addGold(const int gold);
    bool isDead();

private:
    std::string m_name;
    char m_symbol;
    int m_health;
    int m_damage;
    int m_gold;
};
```

Creature.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Creature.h"




Creature::Creature(const std::string & name, const char symbol, const int health, const int damage, const int gold)
    :m_name(name), m_symbol(symbol), m_health(health), m_damage(damage), m_gold(gold)
{
}

Creature::~Creature()
{
}

void Creature::reduceHealth(const int healthMinus)
{
    m_health -= healthMinus;
}

void Creature::addGold(const int gold)
{
    m_gold += gold;
}

bool Creature::isDead()
{
    if (m_health>0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Player.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Creature.h"
#include <string>

class Player :
    public Creature
{
public:
    Player(const std::string &name, const char symbol='@', const int health=10, const int damage=1, const int gold=0);
    ~Player();
    const int getLevel() { return m_level; }
    void levelUp();
    bool hasWon();
private:
    int m_level;
};
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Player.h"




Player::Player(const std::string & name, const char symbol, const int health, const int damage, const int gold)
    :Creature(name,symbol,health,damage,gold)
{
}

Player::~Player()
{
}

void Player::levelUp()
{
    ++m_level;
}

bool Player::hasWon()
{
    if (m_level>=20)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Intellisense errors are not compiler errors. 2. What is your anonymous instance of Player good for?

Comment: I was not planning to use an anonymous object but kind of slipped into it. And the fact that it throws out an error confuses me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Player(name);` does not do what you think it does. It declares a new variable `name` of type `Player` and calls a default constructor. If you want to instantiate an anonymous `Player` variable then you need to write

```
(Player(name));
// or
Player{name}; // list initialization since C++11
```